# Where does Outlook/Windows store saved PST passwords?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016, password-management

When attempting to open a password-protected PST file in Outlook, the prompt has a checkbox option to "Save this password in your password list."

My questions are:

1. Where is this mysterious "password list" they speak of?
2. Is there a way to clear entries in the password list, whether a single entry or the entire list?

Places I have checked:

- Options inside of Outlook (both Regular and Trust Center)
- Windows Credential Manager
- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook`
- `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles`
- `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook`

There's a metric ton of data inside `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook`, so it might actually be there, but it's not obvious at all.

Here's about as close as I got:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Default Outlook Profile\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000007
    clsid               REG_SZ      {ED475414-B0D6-11D2-8C3B-00104B2A6676}
    Mini UID            REG_DWORD   0xa88d937c
    Service UID         REG_BINARY  5956A7B143C9144E9463F8AD0F89D998
    Service Name        REG_SZ      MSPST MS
    MAPI Provider       REG_DWORD   0x4
    Account Name        REG_SZ      <<PST_FILENAME_HERE>>
    Preferences UID     REG_BINARY  B5FFAA5C41AE1949A11E3AE603C65797
```

**Edit:** One thing I discovered is that if you detach (close) the PST file, exit and re-run Outlook, then re-open the PST file, it will ask you for the password again.